# Android navigation bar looks bad on Lollipop

Tags: android

I have some problems with the translucent navigation and title bar in our app. It looks very bad.

On the Splashscreen the background behind the navigation bar is broken directly on the border to the main screen. The complete background screen is not completely expanded to the background of the translucent navigation bar.

The other problem is, that the title bar is grey and das not have the color of the action bar. The title bar have the color of the

```
android:windowBackground
```

Is it possible to expand the style of the action bar to the title bar?

Comment: since you do not have enough reps to post an image can you maybe link to an image explaining what your problem is?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5g_MttTC7ZIYkltejZhNjlhV0E&authuser=0 and https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5g_MttTC7ZIMWQwMjlqY0tBcHc&authuser=0

Comment: And when i out my theme to: `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>` the background will expand unter the navigation bars :-(